# Angular 12, Drag-and-drop with replace-list (placeholder-list)

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I use Angular 12 and Material-design.

I have two lists out of the example [d&d material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples#cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting) and everything works fine. The default behavior is to move one item of list A to list B. This means the element of list A is removed and this specific element is added to list B.

What I try to achieve is, that list B is a list of placeholders. That means the element I dragged from list A is removed and replaced with the element of list B I dropped it.

**Example:**

**List A**

- elem1
- elem2
- elem3

**List B**

- placeholder1
- placeholder2
- placeholder3

Now a drag elem2 of list A and drop it over "placeholder1" of list B. The result should be

**List A**

- elem1
- elem3

**List B**

- elem2
- placeholder2
- placeholder3

I was not able to figure out, how to do this ?

**UPDATE:**

current html

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
    <mat-drawer class="sideMenu" mode="side" role="dragAndDrop" position="end" opened>
      <div class="sideNav-container">
        <div 
        cdkDropList 
        #moviesList="cdkDropList" 
        [cdkDropListData]="MoviesList"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneMovieList]" 
        class="drag-list-sidenav" 
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
            <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let moviesList of MoviesList" cdkDrag>
              <span mat-raised-button
                matTooltip="bla"
                matTooltipPosition="left" class="">{{moviesList}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content class="sideMainContent">
      <div class="container">
        <div 
        cdkDropList 
        #doneMovieList="cdkDropList" 
        [cdkDropListData]="MoviesWatched"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[moviesList]" 
        class="movie-list" 
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"
        >
          <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let moviesWatched of MoviesWatched" cdkDrop>{{moviesWatched}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
```

current TS:

```
export class ListComponent{


// Transfer Items Between Lists
  MoviesList: string[] = [
    'The Far Side of the World',
    'Morituri',
    'Napoleon Dynamite',
    'Pulp Fiction',
    'Blade Runner',
    'Cool Hand Luke',
    'Heat',
    'Juice'
  ];

  MoviesWatched: string[] = [
    'shouled be Placeholde1',
    'shouled be Placeholde2',
  ];


  constructor(){}



  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am trying to achieve the same thing.